# String.Format on a datetime field

Tags: vb.net, datetime, string-formatting

I am trying to get the time part (24h) of a datetime field

```
Dim Dt as datetime =#1/1/1900 8:00:00 PM#
Dim Str as string = String.Format(Dt, "HH:mm")
```

Which returns `"1/1/1900 8:00:00 pm"`

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the overridden `ToString` that exists on `DateTime`:

```
Dt.ToString("HH:mm")
```

Comment: Wow, this one works, but what was wrong with the first option?

Comment: String.Format() is for using placeholders like {0}, {1} and pass values as parameters.

Answer (score 3):

> what was wrong with the first option?

The String.Format() method has 5 overloads, none of which have two arguments that can take a DateTime as the first argument.  What happens next depends on which way you like to use Visual Basic.  You can put this at the top of your source code file:

```
 Option Strict On
```

and the VB.NET compiler gets picky about your code.  You'll now get a compile time error:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Format' can be called with these arguments

Clearly you have it off so it tries to make to make tea from the leaves you give it.  There is exactly one overload of String.Format() that can still be called, it the Format(String, Object) overload.  With was intended to write code like this:

```
 Dim str = String.Format("The time is {0:HH:mm}", Dt)
```

A feature called composite formatting.  In your case, this method can only be called if the VB.NET compiler first converts the DateTime to a string automatically.  In effect you'll call:

```
 Dim str = String.Format("1/1/1900 8:00:00 pm", "HH:mm")
```

Which doesn't do what you hoped it does.

It is usually best to learn VB.NET coding by having the Option Strict always turned on.  And only turn it off when you know the language well enough to survive accidents like this.  You can tell Visual Studio to *always* turn the option on.  Tools + Options, Projects and Solution, VB Defaults and change the Option Strict selection to On.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Date.ToString`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.90).aspx